# Using SQL query to create new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL Server, how would I create a new column from a data query, e.g. say I had a table with a UNIX timestamp -

```
timestamp  | value
------------------
1468073257 |  15
1468073589 |  22
```

the following query outputs the SQL date object for each timestamp

```
Select
    dateadd(S, [timestamp], '1970-01-01')
From myTable
```

how would I use the above query to amend the table such that it looked like:

```
timestamp  |         datetime          | value
----------------------------------------------
1468073257 |  2016-07-09 14:07:37.000  |  15
1468073589 |  2016-07-09 18:12:56.000  |  22
```

I suppose it is sort of like a `SELECT... INTO` but within a table

Comment: 1) alter the table to add the new column 1st.  `ALTER TABLE myTable ADD [newColName] datetime NULL;`   2) write an update statement that states `Update myTable set NewColName = dateadd(s,timestamp],'1970-01-01')` and execute it.  Note unless you drop and recreate the table with the desired specific order, the new column will be added to the end of the table.  but column order really shouldn't matter so why bother?

Comment: You might also consider adding it as a computed column: `ALTER TABLE [YourTable] ADD [datetime] AS DATEADD(SECOND, [timestamp], '19700101');`. You won't be able to `PERSIST` this though.

Comment: @Larnu wise... very wise... especially if the new column should always reflect the current value of timestamp.  it becomes self maintaining that way.  If however the requirement is that it just be set once; then altering the table becomes necessary.  Just depends.

Comment: I would recommend @xQbert 's answer, if the table and data is static; as the data will be contained in the table and thus SARGable. If the data isn't static, then a Computed Column might be the better answer, as the column will always contain the date value, however, as it isn't `PERSISTED`, the value will need to be calculated at run time; meaning that queries against it may not be SARGable, or run as quickly. You also have the option of adding a `DEFAULT` value to the column (which'll work if `timestamp` value doesn't change but rows can will be added.) Depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is likely being populated by existing applications, a schema change could potentially break these applications.

One solution would be to make a [`VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql).

```
CREATE VIEW vw_myTable
AS
SELECT timestamp, DATEADD(S, timestamp, '1970-01-01') AS datetime, value
FROM myTable
```

Querying the view.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table exists you can use INSERT INTO and SELECT statements.
For example:

```
INSERT INTO <your_table_name>(timestamp, datetime, value)
SELECT
   timestamp AS [timestamp],
   dateadd(S, [timestamp], '1970-01-01') AS datetime,
   value AS [value]
From myTabl
```

If you don't have a table but want to create a new one then you can use SELECT ... INTO

For example:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp AS [timestamp],
    dateadd(S, [timestamp], '1970-01-01') AS datetime,
    value AS [value]
INTO <your_new_table> 
FROM myTabl
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not adding any new data (only derived/formatted data), I think it's better to add a computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD [FormattedDateColumnName] AS DATEADD(SECOND,[timestamp],'1/1/1970')
```